# Dictionary not copying in to other dictionary with exception: Dictionary argument is not a NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml-parsing, nsdictionary

I am using the following code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *farmGatesDict  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] 
                 initWithDictionary:[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"FarmGates"]];

        NSLog(@"value from dictionary : %@", [farmGatesDict objectForKey:@"FarmGate"]);


NSMutableDictionary *farmDetailDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] 
                 initWithDictionary:[farmGatesDict objectForKey:@"FarmGate"]];

NSLog(@"%@", farmGateString);
```

I am using this because this dictionary is a parsed xml file and I want to traverse the tree. My first code which is for `farmGatesDict` works well but for second that is `farmDetailDict` application is getting crashed with following exception:

> -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:]: dictionary argument is not an NSDictionary'

Please suggest me were I am lacking behind..

Below is the NSLog data...

```
2012-12-28 15:40:05.223 FarmGates[6170:c07] value from dictionary : (
        {
        address =         {
            text = "\n        2873 Huon Highwway, 2km south of Huonville, over the bridge on river side of road.";
        };
        contact =         {
            text = "\n        Contact 03 6264 1474";
        };
        description =         {
            text = "\n        Shed Door Sales. Arguably the longest standing and most popular road side stall in the Huon. Incorporated with a modern apple packing facility and featuring the refrigerated displays this ensures the freshest stock direct from the grower.";
        };
        fruits =         {
            fruit =             (
                                {
                    text = "\n        \n          Cherries";
                },
                                {
                    text = "\n          Apple";
                }
            );
            text = "\n        ";
        };
        id = 1;
        images =         {
            image =             (
                                {
                    text = "\n        \n          a1.jpg";
                },
                                {
                    text = "\n          b1.jpg";
                },
                                {
                    text = "\n          c1.jpg";
                }
            );
            text = "\n        ";
        };
        latitude =         {
            text = "\n        -43.04964";
        };
        longitude =         {
            text = "\n        147.03903";
        };
        name =         {
            text = "\n  \n  \n        Griggs Grower Direct apples and cherries";
        };
        open =         {
            text = "\n        Open daily except Christmas and Boxing Day.";
        };
        region =         {
            text = "\n        Huon Valley";
        };
        services =         {
            service =             {
                text = "\n        \n            NA";
            };
            text = "\n        ";
        };
        text = "\n    ";
    },
)
```

Comment: check whether your *[farmGatesDict objectForKey:@"FarmGate"]* is returning a dictionary or not.

Comment: I got the problem which is while I am using the xml parsed dictionary (xmlDictionary) which contains nested tags and when ever nested tags come "(" sign is coming which is not the starting sign of a dictionary. Still I am not having solution can any one please suggest something..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an array , as can easily be seen from the `NSLog`.

```
(
        {
        address =         {
            text = "\n        2873 Huon Highwway, 2km south of Huonvil
```

So use `objectAtIndex:` first then go for `objectForKey:`

```
NSMutableDictionary *farmDetailDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:farmGatesDict[0]];
```

Comment: I have'nt used a single word named array in my app and this NSLog is for following code which is for dictionary only.        NSLog(@"value from dictionary : %@", [farmGatesDict objectForKey:@"FarmGate"]);

Comment: Nslog of dictionary starts with {, while for array (. Thats why i said it contains array. Have you checked with my code? if still error can you send me your code? my email id in my profile.

Comment: that sign is coming because I am xmlDictionary consist of parsed data from xml file and whenever nested tags come this sign occurs. And you are right problem is exactly the same can you suggest solution as I cant send code as its a project data

Comment: try nslogging as `[... class]`, if it gives dictionary than cool, otherwise some other way you have to move.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `[farmGatesDict objectForKey:@"FarmGate"]` is not returning an NSDictionary. Check what type is it.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the following line **before** the line which is crashing..

```
NSLog(@"value from dictionary : %@", [farmGatesDict objectForKey:@"FarmGate"]);
```

and post the NSLog result.. I would bet the value you are getting is not an `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

check return value of

```
farmGatesDict objectForKey:@"FarmGate"]
```

try `NSLog` it

Answer (score 0):

I doubt  `[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"FarmGates"]` doesn't return a `NSDictionary`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *farmGatesDict  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] 
                 initWithDictionary:xmlDictionary];
```

It should be working.